# Problem with Julia function to convert seconds to hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: julia

I have this code for Julia to convert seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds, however when I run it I just get `(0, 0, 0)` as the output. Can someone tell me whats wrong with this?

```
function convert_from_seconds(sec::Int64)
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0

    time = (hours, minutes, seconds)

    if sec < 60
        seconds = sec
    elseif sec < 3600
        minutes = floor(sec / 60)
        seconds = sec % 60
    elseif sec < 216000
        hours = floor(sec / 3600)
        minutes = floor(hours % 3600)
        seconds = minutes % 60
    end
    return time
end
```

Comment: Not much of a julia user (yet), but what if you put `time = (hours, minutes, seconds)` *after* calculating all the correct values, instead of before.

Comment: Also the line `minutes = floor(hours % 3600)` seems like a bug. You can't calculate the minutes from just the hours. Should be `floor((sec % 3600) / 60)`. Similarly `seconds = sec % 60` in all cases---can't compute seconds from the minutes even if there are more than 3600 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different approach, and I'm a Julia noob, but this seems to work on the test cases I created and seems a little simpler. As mentioned in comments, I think your issues were (a) creating `time` while hours, minutes, and seconds were 0 instead of after calculating them and (b) some bad logic in the calculations.

```
function convert_from_seconds(sec::Int64)
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = sec % 60

    if sec >= 60
        minutes = floor(sec / 60)
    end
    if minutes >= 60
        hours = floor(minutes / 60)
        minutes = minutes % 60
    end
    time = (hours, minutes, seconds)
    return time
    end
```

I ran these tests, and all worked as expected:

```
print(convert_from_seconds(0))
print(convert_from_seconds(1))
print(convert_from_seconds(59))
print(convert_from_seconds(60))
print(convert_from_seconds(61))
print(convert_from_seconds(120))
print(convert_from_seconds(121))
print(convert_from_seconds(7270))
print(convert_from_seconds(3600))
print(convert_from_seconds(3601))
```

Comment: Okay that would make sense thank you. And yes I see what you are saying with doing seconds as `sec % 60`. Thanks!!

Comment: You can also use [`fld`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.fld) for floored division.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another approach you might want to consider:

```
function convert_from_seconds(sec::Int)
    x, seconds = divrem(sec, 60)
    hours, minutes = divrem(x, 60)
    hours, minutes, seconds
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Conisder using the standard `Dates` API and its arithmetic - it's great! and more elegant than writing your own functions:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> s = Time(0) + Second(4000)
01:06:40

julia> hour(s), minute(s), second(s)
(1, 6, 40)
```

The above code will not give the desired result if you consider 24 hours or more

```
julia> s = DateTime(0) + Second(4*3600*24+4000)
0000-01-05T01:06:40

julia> year(s), (month(s)-1), (day(s)-1), hour(s), minute(s), second(s)
(0, 0, 4, 1, 6, 40)
```

There is no zero-month or zero-day so we needed to subtract `1`.

Comment: This is a very nice and recommended approach if you want to work with date-time structures. When you just want to do a conversion it will be a problematic for negative values of seconds (as it will count down from 24:00:00).

Answer (score 0):

As a software engineer, you must be able to 
HANDLE ANY VALID INPUTS

```
function convert_from_seconds(sec::Int64)
    if sec == 0
        return (0,0,0)
    elseif  sec < 0
        positive_result = convert_from_seconds(-1 * sec)
        return (-1 * positive_result[1],-1 * positive_result[2],-1 * positive_result[3])
    else
        seconds = sec % 60
        mins    = sec ÷ 60
        minutes = mins % 60
        hours   = mins ÷ 60
        return (hours,minutes,seconds)
    end    
end 

println(  50  ," ",convert_from_seconds(   50 ))
println( 100  ," ",convert_from_seconds(  100 ))
println( 2050 ," ",convert_from_seconds( 2050 ))
println( 4050 ," ",convert_from_seconds( 4050 ))
println( -50  ," ",convert_from_seconds(  -50 ))
println(-100  ," ",convert_from_seconds( -100 ))
println(-2050 ," ",convert_from_seconds(-2050 ))
println(-4050 ," ",convert_from_seconds(-4050 ))
```

Here is the sample run

```
Starting Julia...
           _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.3 (2018-12-18)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

50 (0, 0, 50)
100 (0, 1, 40)
2050 (0, 34, 10)
4050 (1, 7, 30)
-50 (0, 0, -50)
-100 (0, -1, -40)
-2050 (0, -34, -10)
-4050 (-1, -7, -30)
```

Now I will demostrate why I am not a SOFTWARE ENGINEER. Smallest value of Int64 is -2^63 ( -1 * big(2) ^ 63 == -9223372036854775808 ) and the largest value of Int64 is 2^63 - 1 (big(2) ^ 63 - 1 == 9223372036854775807)

```
julia> convert_from_seconds( -9223372036854775808 )
ERROR: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] convert_from_seconds(::Int64) at ./untitled-7674d416d9e0628b948f1f3731dd1ecc:5 (repeats 80000 times)
```